# Get ID from selectize.js to form

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

I'm trying to set up a form on my site, and want to use some dynamic dropdown.

I found Selectize.js, which seems like a good solution, however I'm struggling to find out how to get the ID's from the selected option when I post the form.

As in user selects "Banana" and selectize should return 2 as value for the post

The obvious answer would of course be to change `valueField` to `'id'` however that messes up the `createFilter` so that's a no go..

I've made a jsfiddle with what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/imfpa/Lh3anheq/16/

HTML:

```
<form>
    <select id="item-type" placeholder="Choose type...">
    </select>
</form>
```

javascript:

```
function hasOwnPropertyCaseInsensitive(obj, property) {
    var props = [];
    for (var i in obj) if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) props.push(i);
    var prop;
    while (prop = props.pop()) if (prop.toLowerCase() === property.toLowerCase()) return true;
    return false;
}

var REGEX = '[a-zA-ZæøåÆØÅ][a-zA-ZæøåÆØÅ ]*[a-zA-ZæøåÆØÅ]';

$('#item-type').selectize({
    persist: true,
    valueField: 'text',
    labelField: 'text',
    searchField: ['text'],
    options: [
        {id: '1', text: 'Apple'},
        {id: '2', text: 'Banana'},
        {id: '3', text: 'Orange'},
        {id: '4', text: 'Cherry'},

    ],    

    createFilter: function(input) {
        var match, regex;

        regex = new RegExp('^' + REGEX + '$', 'i');
        match = input.match(regex);
        if (match) {
        console.log(match[0]);
            return !hasOwnPropertyCaseInsensitive(this.options, match[0]);
        }

        return false;
    },
    create: true
});
```

Comment: 1. Do not see how the `id` breaks the `createFilter`. 2. Think the `select` should have the `name` attribute specified. 3. Your `REGEX` can be greatly simplified with `[a-zA-ZæøåÆØÅ]{2,}`, if I get right your intention there (do you check for the min length of 2?).

Comment: Thank you for the simplified regex - yes it was my intention to check for min length of 2. The thing with the ```createFilter```is, if I change the ```valueField```to ```id``` - for some reason unbeknownst to me, it will always return ```true``` thus breaking the filter that is supposed to only let the user create values that are not already in the list..

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but why do you let users create new values if the allowed values are *already* in the list..?

Comment: That is exactly my point! I do NOT want to allow users to create values that are already in the list.. but if you change the ```valueField``` to ```id```- it will allow the user to to do so - which is what I want to avoid. That is why I wrote in my post that changing ```valueField```is a no-go

Comment: I am no expert in `selectize.js`, but [according to the docs](https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/usage.md#general) you just need to remove `create: true` (it is `false` by default) and remove the `createFilter`, if you do not want to let users create new items. Here is [an updated jsfiddle of yours](http://jsfiddle.net/Lh3anheq/34/) that should do exactly what you need.

Comment: Thank you for your effort 0x2D9A3, but it seems as if you've completely missed the point of my question. I have already read the documentation. The user should be allowed to create an entry - but only if that entry does not already exist.

Comment: Okay, see my answer below. Hope this is something you want to achieve!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/json/Lh3anheq/35/)** (http://jsfiddle.net/json/Lh3anheq/35/)

Okay, based on our discussion in the comments above, you want the `selectize.js` to return the `id` of the selected item, and also let users create unique items.

You are right about the `id`: you just need to replace the `valueField: 'text'` with `valueField: 'id'`.

Now we need to fix the decision making in your function `hasOwnPropertyCaseInsensitive`.
The first argument in this function is an object of objects. If you see the console output, for `this.options` of your `selectize` element, you will see roughly the following structure (`valueField` is already replaced with `id` here):

```
{
    idOfItem1: {
        id: idOfItem1,
        text: textOfItem1
    },
    idOfItem2: ...
}
```

Here is what the web inspector prints out for `console.log(this.options)`:

[image: console output]

So, we can iterate over all objects and still have the **display value** in the field `text`, and this is exactly the string that we need to compare against the user input for uniqueness.

```
function hasOwnPropertyCaseInsensitive(options, userValue) {
    var exists = false;

    for (var option in options) {
        if (options.hasOwnProperty(option)) {
            if (options[option].text.toLowerCase() === userValue.toLowerCase()) {
                exists = true;
                break; // break from the loop when the match is found. return true works as well.
            }
        }   
    }

    return exists;
}
```

Note! The `id` of an element created by a user will be the same as the display value. I.e. if I add a new element to the list, e.g. `Test`, it will look like this:

```
{
    Test: {
        id: "Test",
        text: "Test"
    }
}
```

Please see the **[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/json/Lh3anheq/35/)** (http://jsfiddle.net/json/Lh3anheq/35/) and let me know if I missed something.

Comment: Thank you so much :) That did the trick - and thanks for the very informative explanation.